# CSS Class for page title

Tags: 2013, master-page, css, custom-masterpage

SharePoint 2013

I need to edit a master page so that when the title of the page is displayed the font size is smaller than the default. Can someone give me the code?

Comment: which SharePoint version?

Comment: Version is 2013

Comment: You have the font size specified twice in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page Title is rendered as

[image]

Try this

```
.ms-core-pageTitle
{  
     font-size:2.77em;
     white-space:nowrap;
     color:pink; /*Let us test colour*/
     font-size:9.77em;/*make it huge*/
     /*You edits here*/
}
```

Override the above in you master page or custom css file.

Comment: Can I use this in a CEWP as well?

Comment: Yes. But in that case it will get only applied to the page you are adding the CEWP.

Comment: Prefer css over master page