# Hide/Remove Page Title - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to hide or remove the Page Title on specific pages in SharePoint online? Any assistence in where I should look to acheive this is appreciated.

Comment: Yes it can be. You can do it using css or js

Comment: Check out the [old discussion](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120177/css-class-for-page-title). In the css add "display:none"

Comment: The other option can be to go to the Page library, select the item representing the page and edit its properties. Remove the text in Title field and save it.

Comment: Hi Nadeem, does this change the page URL? Is this option availbale for multiple pages?

Comment: It won't change the Url of the page. yes, the option is available on all pages.

Comment: I get an error: You can't leave this blank.

Comment: The Title field has been marked as required. Remove this restriction by going into list settings page.

Comment: Hi Nadeem, can you help me navigate to List Settings page in SP Online? I can't locate this

Answer (score 12):

Add a script editor web part on the page and paste following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
      document.querySelector("#pageTitle").style.display = 'none';
})();
</script>
```

Follow [this link](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/05/20/how-to-use-script-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) for adding script editor web part.

Comment: Hi Atish, I followed the link for adding the script editopr web part and pasted that code inside the snippet, but the page is still showing the page title, and alos now the code you provided is also visible on the page. Did i misunderstand a step?

Comment: Wait I am updating answer with full code

Comment: Try my update. Full code is given

Comment: Thank you for the full code Atish. The code is no longer visible on the page, but unfortunately the Title of the page i still visible.

Comment: It should work! Let me try in my site

Comment: Check the update. It does not work without `type="text/javascript"`. @CliffN

Comment: Hmm, still not working for me. Am i possibly missing something in my setup of SP Online?

Comment: @CliffN, can you try the no code solution provided in the comment?

Comment: Not sure why javascript wouldnt work for me. I spent ages trying to figure it out with no luck. i ended up solving this by changing the master page

Comment: Any way to do this with SharePoint Online Modern? Seems not.

Comment: Please help vote this up for Modern Pages.  We would like feature to hide parts of modern pages including:  Title, Search, Logo and Publish Bar.  https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/19280308-remove-banner-and-header-title-from-modern-pages

Comment: Script editor not available in O365. https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/where-are-the-content-editor-and-script-editor-web-parts-in-sharepoint-ed6cc9ce-8b2a-480c-a655-1b9d7615cdbd

Answer (score 5):

You can attach below css to your master page.

```
    <style>
        #pageTitle
        {
           display:none;
        }
    </style>
```

Or you can add JavaScript function using script-editor web part mentioned by **Atish Dipongkor** in his answer.

Comment: If OP adds it on master page, then it will be applied for all pages. He has asked for specific page

Comment: Hi Dikesh, if i do decide to hide for all pages, are you aware of any helpful steps you can point me to in order to identify my master page, and add the css you have provided in the correct place?

Comment: If you have you custom master page then add this css code to the css file you are using in that master page. If you want to hide this on particular page then add this css code in content editor webpart on that page. It will work like charm

Answer (score 4):

There are two titles on a page:

[image: Title elements on a page]

1. The name of the site displayed at the top of the page by default. This title has element ID pageTitle.
2. The name of the content page (for instance a wiki page), which is loaded below the top navigation and contains your page content. This title has element ID pageContentTitle

Let's say you want to hide the name of the content page (option 2 above), then paste the following code into a script editor web part on the page:

```
<script language="javascript">

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("HidePageContentTitle");

function HidePageContentTitle()

{

document.getElementById('pageContentTitle').style.visibility = 'hidden';

} 

</script>
```

You will have to do this on all pages where you want to hide the page title.

Comment: Hello, @perjar, Thank you for your detailed answer, We hope your awesome posts will continue!  So could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thanks!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
      document.querySelector("#pageContentTitle").style.display = 'none';
})();
</script>

Comment: Adding to what Atish Dipongkor wrote earlier, his code snippet hides the site title, not the page title. If you take his code and use the identifyer pageContentTitle instead of pageTitle you will hide the page title instead. 
I actually prefer this way come to think of it. It completely supresses the title so that the page content is shifted up, whereas my previous tip only makes the title invisible but it still takes up space on the page.

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
      document.querySelector("#pageContentTitle").style.display = 'none';
})();
</script>

Answer (score 1):

put custom css to hide the text in master page. This will remove the title from all pages. If you need for specific pages add a content editor web part in the page and add the custom css.

Answer (score 1):

Put a custom class on a custom css file.(From master page settings > Alternate css you can point to that additional file)

```
.hiddenPageTitle {display: none;}
```

then only on that specific page use a piece of script to add that class to page title. Could be in a script or content editor, or if you have too many pages and you have a way to identify the page from it's type you can wrap it into an if block and add to master page. (You also will need JQuery to use the script below)

```
$( "#pageTitle" ).addClass( "hiddenPageTitle" );
```

Hope this helps.