# Hiding "Site Name" in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, title

Can you please advise how to hide a "Site Name" in SharePoint Online? I tried to leave the name blank in the Site Pages but was not able to republish the site as a message prompted that you cannot leave the site name blank.

Comment: Are you using Modern Site or Classic Site experience?

Answer (score 0):

We can handle this through css class by using script editor web part or SPFx webpart.. debug the site home page using F12... get the css class name of the site title....then inject the css code like below :

```
    <style type="text/css">  
    #pageTitle  

      {  

       display:none;  

       }  

     </style>
```

**Reference URL :**

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/hide-the-title-on-a-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-site-using-css

**How to enable script editor web part in SharePoint online:**

https://global-sharepoint.com/2019/08/23/how-to-enable-script-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-online-site/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a modern Site Page, content editor web part or script editor web part is not available.

One recommended way to apply customization on modern pages is to use SharePoint Framework Extensions (SPFx).

Please see the references below.

[Customizing "modern" site pages.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages)

[Overview of SharePoint Framework Extensions.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions)

Another post for your reference.

[Hide/Remove Page Title - SharePoint Online.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191426/hide-remove-page-title-sharepoint-online/191427)